# Issue with Email not sending using Mandrill -> Deploying to Heroku

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, heroku, actionmailer, mandrill

I am setting up my AacionMailer and in all honesty have never done this before.. I have watched video after video and read post after post burt to no avail...

the log error I am catching through PapertrailApp is **Net::SMTPServerBusy (454 4.7.1 : Relay access denied ):**

I can not seem to get mandrill to send the confirmation email to me to sign into the app. I am using locahost:3000 for development and just catching the links to confirm and thats working fine but for production... kinda need this to work..

this is my production.rb file:

```
  config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp
  config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { :host => 'patrolprorms.heroku.com' }

  config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
  :address => "smtp.mandrillapp.com",
  :port => 25,
  :user_name => ENV['MANDRILL_USERNAME'],
  :password => ENV['MANDRILL_API_KEY'],
  :authentication => 'plain',
  :enable_starttls_auto => true,
  :openssl_verify_mode  => 'none'
}
```

This is my development.rb file

```
  config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp
  config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { :host => 'localhost:3000' }

  config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
  :address => "smtp.mandrillapp.com",
  :port => 465,
  :user_name => ENV['MADRILL_USERNAME'],
  :password => ENV['MANDRILL_API_KEY'],
  :authentication => 'plain',
  :enable_starttls_auto => true,
}
```

this was the error I received when I attempted to use port 2525

`Net::SMTPServerBusy (421 4.7.0 relay-7.us-east-1.relay-prod Error: too many errors ):`

Using port 465 i get this error

```
at=error code=H12 desc="Request timeout" method=POST path="/users/confirmation" host=patrolprorms.herokuapp.com request_id=8dfa122b-ab01-4dbc-97d6-0e7640014f08 fwd="68.144.5.70" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=30001ms status=503 bytes=0
```

Based on the errors i think im making some progress??? or loosing more hair.. not sure which just yet.

this is the log file generated by heroku --tail (I don't even have a clue where to begin with this my apologies for the length. **PLEASE DONT HESITATE TO COMMENT TO ASK TO SEE MORE OF MY FILES!!!**

```
2015-08-05T03:13:10.057799+00:00 app[web.2]: source=rack-timeout id=2e30bfc7-6b34-4a87-872b-438c09f9cf71 wait=6ms timeout=15000ms state=ready
2015-08-05T03:13:10.061201+00:00 app[web.2]: Started POST "/users/confirmation" for 68.144.5.70 at 2015-08-05 03:13:10 +0000
2015-08-05T03:13:10.058707+00:00 app[web.2]: source=rack-timeout id=2e30bfc7-6b34-4a87-872b-438c09f9cf71 wait=6ms timeout=15000ms service=1ms state=active
2015-08-05T03:13:10.080546+00:00 app[web.2]: Processing by Devise::ConfirmationsController#create as HTML
2015-08-05T03:13:10.097976+00:00 app[web.2]:   User Load (1.2ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."email" = $1  ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT 1  [["email", "swilson@taurenltd.com"]]
2015-08-05T03:13:10.080589+00:00 app[web.2]:   Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"KllMOhJfb7tOE4s2XaKAB5XMl7Mnb2nwaz1uyY5lyKBzUBSkaEeBW0Kbwvw+DfVVJzzErJYh1Td3LjKBFWBU1w==", "user"=>{"email"=>"swilson@taurenltd.com"}, "commit"=>"Resend confirmation instructions"}
2015-08-05T03:13:10.092454+00:00 app[web.2]:   User Load (1.7ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."unconfirmed_email" = $1  ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT 1  [["unconfirmed_email", "swilson@taurenltd.com"]]
2015-08-05T03:13:10.324637+00:00 app[web.2]:   User Load (1.4ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."confirmation_token" = $1  ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT 1  [["confirmation_token", "b7f3914b2e94209c6c7c02ee0d43cfab3a5bdd1e96d49611789eecf8989cb1e9"]]
2015-08-05T03:13:10.331436+00:00 app[web.2]:   SQL (1.0ms)  UPDATE "users" SET "confirmation_token" = $1, "confirmation_sent_at" = $2, "updated_at" = $3 WHERE "users"."id" = $4  [["confirmation_token", "b7f3914b2e94209c6c7c02ee0d43cfab3a5bdd1e96d49611789eecf8989cb1e9"], ["confirmation_sent_at", "2015-08-05 03:13:10.325301"], ["updated_at", "2015-08-05 03:13:10.327429"], ["id", 3]]
2015-08-05T03:13:10.344986+00:00 app[web.2]:   Rendered devise/mailer/confirmation_instructions.html.erb (1.6ms)
2015-08-05T03:13:10.326623+00:00 app[web.2]:    (0.7ms)  BEGIN
2015-08-05T03:13:10.334462+00:00 app[web.2]:    (1.9ms)  COMMIT
2015-08-05T03:13:10.678128+00:00 app[web.2]:
2015-08-05T03:13:10.678134+00:00 app[web.2]: Devise::Mailer#confirmation_instructions: processed outbound mail in 340.9ms
2015-08-05T03:13:11.058190+00:00 app[web.2]: source=rack-timeout id=2e30bfc7-6b34-4a87-872b-438c09f9cf71 wait=6ms timeout=15000ms service=1000ms state=active
2015-08-05T03:13:12.058224+00:00 app[web.2]: source=rack-timeout id=2e30bfc7-6b34-4a87-872b-438c09f9cf71 wait=6ms timeout=15000ms service=2000ms state=active
2015-08-05T03:13:13.058225+00:00 app[web.2]: source=rack-timeout id=2e30bfc7-6b34-4a87-872b-438c09f9cf71 wait=6ms timeout=15000ms service=3000ms state=active
2015-08-05T03:13:14.058223+00:00 app[web.2]: source=rack-timeout id=2e30bfc7-6b34-4a87-872b-438c09f9cf71 wait=6ms timeout=15000ms service=4000ms state=active
2015-08-05T03:13:15.058135+00:00 app[web.2]: source=rack-timeout id=2e30bfc7-6b34-4a87-872b-438c09f9cf71 wait=6ms timeout=15000ms service=5000ms state=active
2015-08-05T03:13:16.058333+00:00 app[web.2]: source=rack-timeout id=2e30bfc7-6b34-4a87-872b-438c09f9cf71 wait=6ms timeout=15000ms service=6001ms state=active
2015-08-05T03:13:17.058342+00:00 app[web.2]: source=rack-timeout id=2e30bfc7-6b34-4a87-872b-438c09f9cf71 wait=6ms timeout=15000ms service=7000ms state=active
2015-08-05T03:13:18.058303+00:00 app[web.2]: source=rack-timeout id=2e30bfc7-6b34-4a87-872b-438c09f9cf71 wait=6ms timeout=15000ms service=8000ms state=active
2015-08-05T03:13:19.058618+00:00 app[web.2]: source=rack-timeout id=2e30bfc7-6b34-4a87-872b-438c09f9cf71 wait=6ms timeout=15000ms service=9001ms state=active
2015-08-05T03:13:20.058189+00:00 app[web.2]: source=rack-timeout id=2e30bfc7-6b34-4a87-872b-438c09f9cf71 wait=6ms timeout=15000ms service=10000ms state=active
2015-08-05T03:13:21.058132+00:00 app[web.2]: source=rack-timeout id=2e30bfc7-6b34-4a87-872b-438c09f9cf71 wait=6ms timeout=15000ms service=11000ms state=active
2015-08-05T03:13:22.058166+00:00 app[web.2]: source=rack-timeout id=2e30bfc7-6b34-4a87-872b-438c09f9cf71 wait=6ms timeout=15000ms service=12000ms state=active
2015-08-05T03:13:23.058203+00:00 app[web.2]: source=rack-timeout id=2e30bfc7-6b34-4a87-872b-438c09f9cf71 wait=6ms timeout=15000ms service=13000ms state=active
2015-08-05T03:13:24.058232+00:00 app[web.2]: source=rack-timeout id=2e30bfc7-6b34-4a87-872b-438c09f9cf71 wait=6ms timeout=15000ms service=14000ms state=active
2015-08-05T03:13:25.082651+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=POST path="/users/confirmation" host=patrolprorms.herokuapp.com request_id=2e30bfc7-6b34-4a87-872b-438c09f9cf71 fwd="68.144.5.70" dyno=web.2 connect=1ms service=15025ms status=500 bytes=1755
2015-08-05T03:13:25.059345+00:00 app[web.2]: source=rack-timeout id=2e30bfc7-6b34-4a87-872b-438c09f9cf71 wait=6ms timeout=15000ms service=15001ms state=timed_out
2015-08-05T03:13:25.073324+00:00 app[web.2]:
2015-08-05T03:13:25.073336+00:00 app[web.2]: Rack::Timeout::RequestTimeoutError (Request waited 6ms, then ran for longer than 15000ms):
2015-08-05T03:13:25.073338+00:00 app[web.2]:   vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/net/protocol.rb:155:in `select'
2015-08-05T03:13:25.073339+00:00 app[web.2]:   vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/net/protocol.rb:155:in `rescue in rbuf_fill'
2015-08-05T03:13:25.073340+00:00 app[web.2]:   vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/net/protocol.rb:152:in `rbuf_fill'
2015-08-05T03:13:25.073342+00:00 app[web.2]:   vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/net/protocol.rb:134:in `readuntil'
2015-08-05T03:13:25.073343+00:00 app[web.2]:   vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/net/protocol.rb:144:in `readline'
2015-08-05T03:13:25.073344+00:00 app[web.2]:   vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/net/smtp.rb:932:in `recv_response'
2015-08-05T03:13:25.073345+00:00 app[web.2]:   vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/net/smtp.rb:555:in `block in do_start'
2015-08-05T03:13:25.073346+00:00 app[web.2]:   vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/net/smtp.rb:942:in `critical'
2015-08-05T03:13:25.073348+00:00 app[web.2]:   vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/net/smtp.rb:555:in `do_start'
2015-08-05T03:13:25.073349+00:00 app[web.2]:   vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/net/smtp.rb:520:in `start'
2015-08-05T03:13:25.073351+00:00 app[web.2]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/mail-2.6.3/lib/mail/network/delivery_methods/smtp.rb:112:in `deliver!'
2015-08-05T03:13:25.073352+00:00 app[web.2]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/mail-2.6.3/lib/mail/message.rb:2141:in `do_delivery'
2015-08-05T03:13:25.073353+00:00 app[web.2]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/mail-2.6.3/lib/mail/message.rb:236:in `block in deliver'
2015-08-05T03:13:25.073355+00:00 app[web.2]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionmailer-4.2.3/lib/action_mailer/base.rb:543:in `block in deliver_mail'
2015-08-05T03:13:25.073356+00:00 app[web.2]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.3/lib/active_support/notifications.rb:164:in `block in instrument'
2015-08-05T03:13:25.073358+00:00 app[web.2]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.3/lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'
2015-08-05T03:13:25.073359+00:00 app[web.2]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.3/lib/active_support/notifications.rb:164:in `instrument'
2015-08-05T03:13:25.073360+00:00 app[web.2]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionmailer-4.2.3/lib/action_mailer/base.rb:541:in `deliver_mail'
2015-08-05T03:13:25.073361+00:00 app[web.2]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/mail-2.6.3/lib/mail/message.rb:236:in `deliver'
2015-08-05T03:13:25.073362+00:00 app[web.2]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionmailer-4.2.3/lib/action_mailer/message_delivery.rb:85:in `deliver_now'
2015-08-05T03:13:25.073363+00:00 app[web.2]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/devise-3.4.1/lib/devise/models/authenticatable.rb:176:in `send_devise_notification'
2015-08-05T03:13:25.073365+00:00 app[web.2]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/devise-3.4.1/lib/devise/models/confirmable.rb:102:in `send_confirmation_instructions'
2015-08-05T03:13:25.073366+00:00 app[web.2]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/devise-3.4.1/lib/devise/models/confirmable.rb:117:in `block in resend_confirmation_instructions'
2015-08-05T03:13:25.073367+00:00 app[web.2]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/devise-3.4.1/lib/devise/models/confirmable.rb:211:in `pending_any_confirmation'
2015-08-05T03:13:25.073369+00:00 app[web.2]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/devise-3.4.1/lib/devise/models/confirmable.rb:116:in `resend_confirmation_instructions'
2015-08-05T03:13:25.073370+00:00 app[web.2]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/devise-3.4.1/lib/devise/models/confirmable.rb:265:in `send_confirmation_instructions'
2015-08-05T03:13:25.073371+00:00 app[web.2]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/devise-3.4.1/app/controllers/devise/confirmations_controller.rb:9:in `create'
2015-08-05T03:13:25.073372+00:00 app[web.2]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.3/lib/action_controller/metal/implicit_render.rb:4:in `send_action'
2015-08-05T03:13:25.073373+00:00 app[web.2]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.3/lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:198:in `process_action'
2015-08-05T03:13:25.073375+00:00 app[web.2]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.3/lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:10:in `process_action'
2015-08-05T03:13:25.073376+00:00 app[web.2]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.3/lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:20:in `block in process_action'
2015-08-05T03:13:25.073377+00:00 app[web.2]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.3/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:115:in `call'
2015-08-05T03:13:25.073378+00:00 app[web.2]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.3/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:115:in `call'
2015-08-05T03:13:25.073379+00:00 app[web.2]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.3/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:553:in `block (2 levels) in compile'
2015-08-05T03:13:25.073380+00:00 app[web.2]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.3/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:503:in `call'
2015-08-05T03:13:25.073381+00:00 app[web.2]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.3/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:503:in `call'
2015-08-05T03:13:25.073382+00:00 app[web.2]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.3/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:88:in `run_callbacks'
2015-08-05T03:13:25.073383+00:00 app[web.2]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.3/lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:19:in `process_action'
2015-08-05T03:13:25.073384+00:00 app[web.2]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.3/lib/action_controller/metal/rescue.rb:29:in `process_action'
2015-08-05T03:13:25.073385+00:00 app[web.2]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.3/lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:32:in `block in process_action'
2015-08-05T03:13:25.075049+00:00 app[web.2]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.3/lib/active_support/notifications.rb:164:in `block in instrument'
2015-08-05T03:13:25.075051+00:00 app[web.2]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.3/lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'
2015-08-05T03:13:25.075053+00:00 app[web.2]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.3/lib/active_support/notifications.rb:164:in `instrument'
2015-08-05T03:13:25.075054+00:00 app[web.2]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.3/lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:30:in `process_action'
2015-08-05T03:13:25.075055+00:00 app[web.2]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.3/lib/action_controller/metal/params_wrapper.rb:250:in `process_action'
2015-08-05T03:13:25.075056+00:00 app[web.2]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.3/lib/active_record/railties/controller_runtime.rb:18:in `process_action'
2015-08-05T03:13:25.075058+00:00 app[web.2]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.3/lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:137:in `process'
2015-08-05T03:13:25.075059+00:00 app[web.2]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionview-4.2.3/lib/action_view/rendering.rb:30:in `process'
2015-08-05T03:13:25.075060+00:00 app[web.2]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.3/lib/action_controller/metal.rb:196:in `dispatch'
2015-08-05T03:13:25.075061+00:00 app[web.2]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.3/lib/action_controller/metal/rack_delegation.rb:13:in `dispatch'
2015-08-05T03:13:25.075076+00:00 app[web.2]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.3/lib/action_controller/metal.rb:237:in `block in action'
2015-08-05T03:13:25.075077+00:00 app[web.2]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.3/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:76:in `call'
2015-08-05T03:13:25.075078+00:00 app[web.2]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.3/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:76:in `dispatch'
2015-08-05T03:13:25.075080+00:00 app[web.2]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.3/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:45:in `serve'
2015-08-05T03:13:25.075081+00:00 app[web.2]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.3/lib/action_dispatch/routing/mapper.rb:49:in `serve'
2015-08-05T03:13:25.075082+00:00 app[web.2]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.3/lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:43:in `block in serve'
2015-08-05T03:13:25.075083+00:00 app[web.2]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.3/lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:30:in `each'
2015-08-05T03:13:25.075084+00:00 app[web.2]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.3/lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:30:in `serve'
2015-08-05T03:13:25.075087+00:00 app[web.2]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.3/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:821:in `call'
2015-08-05T03:13:25.075088+00:00 app[web.2]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/newrelic_rpm-3.11.0.283/lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:67:in `call'
2015-08-05T03:13:25.075091+00:00 app[web.2]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/newrelic_rpm-3.11.0.283/lib/new_relic/rack/agent_hooks.rb:30:in `traced_call'
2015-08-05T03:13:25.075092+00:00 app[web.2]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/newrelic_rpm-3.11.0.283/lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:67:in `call'
2015-08-05T03:13:25.075094+00:00 app[web.2]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/newrelic_rpm-3.11.0.283/lib/new_relic/rack/browser_monitoring.rb:23:in `traced_call'
2015-08-05T03:13:25.075095+00:00 app[web.2]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/newrelic_rpm-3.11.0.283/lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:67:in `call'
2015-08-05T03:13:25.075096+00:00 app[web.2]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/warden-1.2.3/lib/warden/manager.rb:35:in `block in call'
2015-08-05T03:13:25.075097+00:00 app[web.2]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/warden-1.2.3/lib/warden/manager.rb:34:in `catch'
2015-08-05T03:13:25.075099+00:00 app[web.2]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/warden-1.2.3/lib/warden/manager.rb:34:in `call'
2015-08-05T03:13:25.075100+00:00 app[web.2]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/newrelic_rpm-3.11.0.283/lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:67:in `call'
2015-08-05T03:13:25.075101+00:00 app[web.2]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/etag.rb:24:in `call'
2015-08-05T03:13:25.075102+00:00 app[web.2]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/newrelic_rpm-3.11.0.283/lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:67:in `call'
2015-08-05T03:13:25.075103+00:00 app[web.2]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/conditionalget.rb:38:in `call'
2015-08-05T03:13:25.075105+00:00 app[web.2]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/newrelic_rpm-3.11.0.283/lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:67:in `call'
2015-08-05T03:13:25.075106+00:00 app[web.2]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/head.rb:13:in `call'
2015-08-05T03:13:25.075108+00:00 app[web.2]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/newrelic_rpm-3.11.0.283/lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:67:in `call'
2015-08-05T03:13:25.075109+00:00 app[web.2]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.3/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/params_parser.rb:27:in `call'
2015-08-05T03:13:25.075110+00:00 app[web.2]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/newrelic_rpm-3.11.0.283/lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:67:in `call'
2015-08-05T03:13:25.075111+00:00 app[web.2]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.3/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/flash.rb:260:in `call'
2015-08-05T03:13:25.075116+00:00 app[web.2]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/newrelic_rpm-3.11.0.283/lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:67:in `call'
2015-08-05T03:13:25.075148+00:00 app[web.2]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:225:in `context'
2015-08-05T03:13:25.075150+00:00 app[web.2]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:220:in `call'
2015-08-05T03:13:25.075151+00:00 app[web.2]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/newrelic_rpm-3.11.0.283/lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:67:in `call'
2015-08-05T03:13:25.075152+00:00 app[web.2]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.3/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/cookies.rb:560:in `call'
2015-08-05T03:13:25.075154+00:00 app[web.2]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/newrelic_rpm-3.11.0.283/lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:67:in `call'
2015-08-05T03:13:25.075155+00:00 app[web.2]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.3/lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:36:in `call'
2015-08-05T03:13:25.075156+00:00 app[web.2]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/newrelic_rpm-3.11.0.283/lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:67:in `call'
2015-08-05T03:13:25.075157+00:00 app[web.2]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.3/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:653:in `call'
2015-08-05T03:13:25.075159+00:00 app[web.2]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/newrelic_rpm-3.11.0.283/lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:67:in `call'
2015-08-05T03:13:25.075160+00:00 app[web.2]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.3/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:29:in `block in call'
2015-08-05T03:13:25.075161+00:00 app[web.2]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.3/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:84:in `run_callbacks'
2015-08-05T03:13:25.075162+00:00 app[web.2]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.3/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:27:in `call'
2015-08-05T03:13:25.075163+00:00 app[web.2]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/newrelic_rpm-3.11.0.283/lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:67:in `call'
2015-08-05T03:13:25.075165+00:00 app[web.2]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.3/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:78:in `call'
2015-08-05T03:13:25.075166+00:00 app[web.2]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/newrelic_rpm-3.11.0.283/lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:67:in `call'
2015-08-05T03:13:25.075167+00:00 app[web.2]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.3/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:17:in `call'
2015-08-05T03:13:25.075168+00:00 app[web.2]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/newrelic_rpm-3.11.0.283/lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:67:in `call'
2015-08-05T03:13:25.075169+00:00 app[web.2]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.3/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:30:in `call'
2015-08-05T03:13:25.075170+00:00 app[web.2]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/newrelic_rpm-3.11.0.283/lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:67:in `call'
2015-08-05T03:13:25.075171+00:00 app[web.2]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.2.3/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:38:in `call_app'
2015-08-05T03:13:25.075172+00:00 app[web.2]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.2.3/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `block in call'
2015-08-05T03:13:25.075173+00:00 app[web.2]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.3/lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `block in tagged'
2015-08-05T03:13:25.075175+00:00 app[web.2]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.3/lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:26:in `tagged'
2015-08-05T03:13:25.075176+00:00 app[web.2]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.3/lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `tagged'
2015-08-05T03:13:25.075177+00:00 app[web.2]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.2.3/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `call'
2015-08-05T03:13:25.075178+00:00 app[web.2]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/newrelic_rpm-3.11.0.283/lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:67:in `call'
2015-08-05T03:13:25.075179+00:00 app[web.2]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.3/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:21:in `call'
2015-08-05T03:13:25.075180+00:00 app[web.2]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/newrelic_rpm-3.11.0.283/lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:67:in `call'
2015-08-05T03:13:25.075182+00:00 app[web.2]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:22:in `call'
2015-08-05T03:13:25.075183+00:00 app[web.2]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/newrelic_rpm-3.11.0.283/lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:67:in `call'
2015-08-05T03:13:25.075185+00:00 app[web.2]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/runtime.rb:18:in `call'
2015-08-05T03:13:25.068901+00:00 app[web.2]:
2015-08-05T03:13:25.075186+00:00 app[web.2]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/newrelic_rpm-3.11.0.283/lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:67:in `call'
2015-08-05T03:13:25.068905+00:00 app[web.2]: Sent mail to swilson@taurenltd.com (14390.5ms)
2015-08-05T03:13:25.068972+00:00 app[web.2]: Date: Wed, 05 Aug 2015 03:13:10 +0000
2015-08-05T03:13:25.068974+00:00 app[web.2]: From: admin@patrolprorms.com
2015-08-05T03:13:25.068975+00:00 app[web.2]: Reply-To: admin@patrolprorms.com
2015-08-05T03:13:25.068976+00:00 app[web.2]: To: swilson@taurenltd.com
2015-08-05T03:13:25.075187+00:00 app[web.2]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.3/lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache_middleware.rb:28:in `call'
2015-08-05T03:13:25.075188+00:00 app[web.2]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/newrelic_rpm-3.11.0.283/lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:67:in `call'
2015-08-05T03:13:25.068978+00:00 app[web.2]: Message-ID: <55c17f46a6750_33fcc653f6490439a0@f547e1bc-2195-4acf-aa76-162e2f3c820a.mail>
2015-08-05T03:13:25.075189+00:00 app[web.2]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.3/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:116:in `call'
2015-08-05T03:13:25.075190+00:00 app[web.2]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/newrelic_rpm-3.11.0.283/lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:67:in `call'
2015-08-05T03:13:25.068979+00:00 app[web.2]: Subject: Confirmation instructions
2015-08-05T03:13:25.075195+00:00 app[web.2]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/sendfile.rb:113:in `call'
2015-08-05T03:13:25.068980+00:00 app[web.2]: Mime-Version: 1.0
2015-08-05T03:13:25.075213+00:00 app[web.2]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/newrelic_rpm-3.11.0.283/lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:67:in `call'
2015-08-05T03:13:25.075215+00:00 app[web.2]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-timeout-0.2.4/lib/rack/timeout.rb:108:in `call'
2015-08-05T03:13:25.075216+00:00 app[web.2]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/newrelic_rpm-3.11.0.283/lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:67:in `call'
2015-08-05T03:13:25.068981+00:00 app[web.2]: Content-Type: text/html;
2015-08-05T03:13:25.075217+00:00 app[web.2]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.2.3/lib/rails/engine.rb:518:in `call'
2015-08-05T03:13:25.075219+00:00 app[web.2]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.2.3/lib/rails/application.rb:165:in `call'
2015-08-05T03:13:25.075220+00:00 app[web.2]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/newrelic_rpm-3.11.0.283/lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:67:in `call'
2015-08-05T03:13:25.075221+00:00 app[web.2]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in `call'
2015-08-05T03:13:25.075222+00:00 app[web.2]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/content_length.rb:15:in `call'
2015-08-05T03:13:25.075223+00:00 app[web.2]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:88:in `service'
2015-08-05T03:13:25.075225+00:00 app[web.2]:   vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:138:in `service'
2015-08-05T03:13:25.075226+00:00 app[web.2]:   vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:94:in `run'
2015-08-05T03:13:25.075232+00:00 app[web.2]:   vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/webrick/server.rb:295:in `block in start_thread'
2015-08-05T03:13:25.075234+00:00 app[web.2]:
2015-08-05T03:13:25.075235+00:00 app[web.2]:
2015-08-05T03:13:25.076101+00:00 app[web.2]: source=rack-timeout id=2e30bfc7-6b34-4a87-872b-438c09f9cf71 wait=6ms timeout=15000ms service=15018ms state=completed
2015-08-05T03:13:25.068985+00:00 app[web.2]:  charset=UTF-8
2015-08-05T03:13:25.068986+00:00 app[web.2]: Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit
2015-08-05T03:13:25.068987+00:00 app[web.2]:
2015-08-05T03:13:25.068988+00:00 app[web.2]: <p>Welcome swilson@taurenltd.com!</p>
2015-08-05T03:13:25.068990+00:00 app[web.2]:
2015-08-05T03:13:25.068991+00:00 app[web.2]: <p>You can confirm your account email through the link below:</p>
2015-08-05T03:13:25.068992+00:00 app[web.2]:
2015-08-05T03:13:25.068994+00:00 app[web.2]: <p><a href="http://patrolprorms.heroku.com/users/confirmation?confirmation_token=6y3Hi7GpaQCvsme54C4_">Confirm my account</a></p>
2015-08-05T03:13:25.068995+00:00 app[web.2]:
2015-08-05T03:13:25.069753+00:00 app[web.2]: Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 14989ms (ActiveRecord: 8.8ms)
Any help will be greatly appreciated to resolve this!
```

Comment: Are you able to connect using a different port (like 2525, 587, or 465 with SSL)? The Mandrill KB has some other suggestions if the port switcheroo doesn't fix it: https://mandrill.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/205582207

Comment: @terrorbox Net::SMTPServerBusy (421 4.7.0 relay-7.us-east-1.relay-prod Error: too many errors ): this was the error I received when i attempted to use port 2525,  using port 465 i get this error at=error code=H12 desc="Request timeout" method=POST path="/users/confirmation" host=patrolprorms.herokuapp.com request_id=8dfa122b-ab01-4dbc-97d6-0e7640014f08 fwd="68.144.5.70" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=30001ms status=503 bytes=0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So when you change the port to 2525, you're connecting to Mandrill's servers but getting errors. "Too many errors" means your server is hitting one kind of error (usually authentication-related), but continuing to try to send in spite of those errors. Then Mandrill is throttling the connection to avoid having continuous connections from servers that aren't fixing the things that are causing errors in the sending process.

To further debug, double check that your Mandrill credentials in ENV['MANDRILL_APIKEY'] are correct, then add the following to your environment files to perform deliveries and raise delivery errors if there are any:

```
config.action_mailer.perform_deliveries = true
config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = true
```

What that will do is make ActionMailer not silently ignore errors, so depending on how you have this set up and which environment you're testing in, there's a risk of exposing those errors to your end users. But it will allow you to see what's actually being written to the SMTP connection to troubleshoot further. You'll need to restart your app before trying to send again.